# PHP- Pagination, same results on all pages

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am new to pagination, and I tried doing it. It partially works. My pagination, brings out the correct number of results on each page as well as the correct number of pages. But the problem is it shows the same results on each page.

Here is the code:

```
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $rows;
//Total row count.


//Number of results we want displayed per page.
$page_rows = 3;
//Last page, page number.
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
//Making sure that last page cannot be less than one.
if($last < 1){
 $last = 1;
}
//Establish pagenum variable;
$pagenum = 1;
//Get paenum variable from the URL if it exists.
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
 $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}
//Making sure the pagenum isn't below one.
if($pagenum < 1){
 $pagenum = 1;
}else if($pagenum > $last){
 $pagenum = $last;
}
//This sets the limit.
$limit =  'LIMIT ' .($pagenum-1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
//Establish the pagination controls.
$paginationCtrls = '';
//If there is more than one page worth of results.
if($last != 1){
 if($pagenum > 1){
    $previous = $pagenum - 1;
    $paginationCtrls .= '<a href = "'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
    //Clickable links that should appear on the left.
    for($i = $pagenum - 4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
        if($i > 0){
            $paginationCtrls .='<a href = "'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        }
    }
}
$paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
for($i = $pagenum+1; $i<= $last; $i++){
    $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
    if($i > $pagenum+4){
        break;
    }
}
if($pagenum != $last){
    $next = $pagenum+1;
    $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a>';
} 
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blogdata2 ORDER BY id DESC ".$limit;
```

I have also tried this during query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blogdata2 ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
```

But none seem to work. What could be the problem here?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do you re-execute the query after you assign `$sql` at the bottom?

Comment: Since you already have the results you want in `$result`, you could just use `mysqli_data_seek` to jump to the row you want to start with, instead of doing another query with `LIMIT`.

Comment: Yes I do re execute the query at the bottom, And also is it not okay to use LIMIT? Is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using LIMIT, and I don't see an obvious problem in the code. But it seems wasteful to run the same query twice.

Comment: If you `echo $sql;`, do you see the expected LIMIT clause? Do you get the correct rows if you run the query by hand?